# How does ps work in distribute Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

After learning multi-gpu sample([multi_gpu_sample](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.11/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10/cifar10_multi_gpu_train.py)), I think the distribute tensorflow is similar with multi-gpu, cpu to ps and gpu to worker.

So, ps's work is collecting gradients from worker , then update the parameter and send and share them to the workers.

But after reading the distribute Tensorflow sample below, I felt confused.
It seems that ps do nothing but join() ops.

How to understand this? Thanks!

```py
import tensorflow as tf

# Flags for defining the tf.train.ClusterSpec
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string("ps_hosts", "",
                           "Comma-separated list of hostname:port pairs")
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string("worker_hosts", "",
                           "Comma-separated list of hostname:port pairs")

# Flags for defining the tf.train.Server
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string("job_name", "", "One of 'ps', 'worker'")
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_integer("task_index", 0, "Index of task within the job")

FLAGS = tf.app.flags.FLAGS


def main(_):
  ps_hosts = FLAGS.ps_hosts.split(",")
  worker_hosts = FLAGS.worker_hosts.split(",")

  # Create a cluster from the parameter server and worker hosts.
  cluster = tf.train.ClusterSpec({"ps": ps_hosts, "worker": worker_hosts})

  # Create and start a server for the local task.
  server = tf.train.Server(cluster,
                           job_name=FLAGS.job_name,
                           task_index=FLAGS.task_index)

  if FLAGS.job_name == "ps":
    server.join()
  elif FLAGS.job_name == "worker":

    # Assigns ops to the local worker by default.
    with tf.device(tf.train.replica_device_setter(
        worker_device="/job:worker/task:%d" % FLAGS.task_index,
        cluster=cluster)):

      # Build model...
      loss = ...
      global_step = tf.Variable(0)

      train_op = tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(0.01).minimize(
          loss, global_step=global_step)

      saver = tf.train.Saver()
      summary_op = tf.merge_all_summaries()
      init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()

    # Create a "supervisor", which oversees the training process.
    sv = tf.train.Supervisor(is_chief=(FLAGS.task_index == 0),
                             logdir="/tmp/train_logs",
                             init_op=init_op,
                             summary_op=summary_op,
                             saver=saver,
                             global_step=global_step,
                             save_model_secs=600)

    # The supervisor takes care of session initialization, restoring from
    # a checkpoint, and closing when done or an error occurs.
    with sv.managed_session(server.target) as sess:
      # Loop until the supervisor shuts down or 1000000 steps have completed.
      step = 0
      while not sv.should_stop() and step < 1000000:
        # Run a training step asynchronously.
        # See `tf.train.SyncReplicasOptimizer` for additional details on how to
        # perform *synchronous* training.
        _, step = sess.run([train_op, global_step])

    # Ask for all the services to stop.
    sv.stop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  tf.app.run()
```

Answer (score 3):

It's a pretty confusing example ([which came from the manual, I believe](https://www.tensorflow.org/how_tos/distributed/)). It will probably be changed as Distributed TensorFlow matures.

Anyway, both "worker" and "ps" are *tasks* (or *jobs* rather, which are just groups of *tasks*), so they're really no different. The difference is what they're supposed to be used for. The idea is that state (e.g. `tf.Variable`) should be on the parameter servers, while operations for calculating state should be on the workers. Instead of achieving this by calling `tf.device` manually everywhere, a helper function named [`tf.train.replica_device_setter`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/train/distributed_execution#replica_device_setter) is used that sets a `tf.Variable`'s device to a parameter server, and the other operations to a worker.

`server.join()` just means that parameter servers will wait on the workers, instead of terminating their client processes immediately.

```py
with tf.device(tf.replica_device_setter(
  worker_device="/job:worker/task:%d" % FLAGS.task_index, 
  cluster=cluster_spec)):

  v1 = tf.Variable(...)  # Automatically assigned to a parameter server.
  train_op = ... # Automatically assigned to the worker.
```

Comment: oh, thank u very much,  I know it. One more thing,  I think ps should do something like collecting data from workers and updating weight to workers. if  operations for calculating state are all on the workers, who is the collector? Just like the multi-gpu sample, gpus calculate their own gradients and cpu collect them to update weight ,then share to the gpus.

Comment: The exact details of how/when a worker gets states to work with, or when a parameter server stores a new state, is something we don't have to think about as Distributed TensorFlow takes care of it behind the scenes when you pin operations and variables to devices in this way.

Comment: I see it. This is indeed a confusing example. Thank you very very much.